# Add specific value to a data.frame column by matching a pattern

Tags: r, pattern-matching, dataframe

I have two data.frames:

```
pattern <- data.frame(pattern = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), val = c(1, 1, 2, 2))

match <- data.frame(match = c("A", "C"))
```

I want to add to my data.frame pattern another column called new_val and assign "X" to each row where the value for column pattern is in the data.frame match otherwise assign "Y"

```
is.element(pattern$pattern, match$match)
```

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

So, the resulting data.frame should look like:

```
    pattern val new_val
1   A       1   X
2   B       1   Y
3   C       2   X
4   D       2   Y
```

I achieved to do it with an ugly for-loop but I am sure this can be pretty much done in a one line R command using fancy stuff :-)

Is anyone able to help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only really posting this since Tyler said "if you wanted a one liner data.table would likely do it" and I knew it was definitely possible with a one liner in base.  I am also assuming `match` had been renamed to `mat`.

```
  pattern$new_val <- c("Y", "X")[(pattern$pattern %in% mat)+1]
  pattern
#  pattern val new_val
#1       A   1       X
#2       B   1       Y
#3       C   2       X
#4       D   2       Y
```

`pattern$pattern %in% mat` is finding which of the elements of pattern are in mat which returns TRUE if it's in mat, FALSE if it's not.  Then I add 1 to make it numeric in the range of 1-2 so that it can be used for indexing.  Then we use that as an index to the self defined vector `c("Y", "X")` and since the index we created is always 1 or 2 we're always able to grab an element of interest.  So in this case we'll grab "Y" if pattern wasn't in mat and "X" if it was - which is what you wanted.

Comment: Indeed! Both solutions are great R code and def better than for-loop solution. Thanks very much again!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way (I renamed your match to mat since there's a pretty important base function named match that you could actually use to solve this problem; in fact `%in%` is a form of `match`:

```
pattern <- data.frame(pattern = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), val = c(1, 1, 2, 2))
mat <- c("A", "C")

pattern$new_val <- "Y"                            #pre allot everything to be Y
pattern$new_val[pattern$pattern %in% mat] <- "X"  #replace any A or C with an X
pattern
```

PS if you wanted a one liner `data.table` would likely do it.

If you wanted something a little more complicated you could use a function from a package I'm working on:

```
library(qdap)

#original problem
pattern$new_val <- text2color(pattern$pattern, list(c("A", "C")), c("X", "Y"))

#extending it
#makes D  a 5
text2color(pattern$pattern, list(c("A", "C"), "D"), c("X", 5, "Y"))
```

This function really is designed to do something else but if you want to grab the essential parts of it you can look at the source code.

Comment: Theoretically you could update this to not require installing from github